# How do I update the factory layout templates in Proficy Change Management?

Tags: templates, change-management, proficy

How do I update the factory layout templates in Proficy Change Management (i.e. where are they located when checked out?). e.g. generic.htm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure:

1. Open Proficy Change Management
2. Check out the desired factory layout
3. Open Explorer (Win-E) and go to C:\fx\fxLayout\FactoryLayoutName
4. Make your changes (edit, create, etc.)
5. Publish and check in the factory layout

The path will vary based on your configuration but it is likely to be similar to what's noted above. Any files you change or add to that folder will be captured when you publish or check in.